# ¿Como puedo crear algo similar a la función gotoxy en python?

Tags: python

he estado investigando sobre C++ y me encontré con la función gotoxy, por lo que me estaba preguntando si es que se puede hacer algo igual o similar en python, me puse a buscar pero no encontré nada, así que no se si siquiera sea posible.

Comment: Si buscas algo para Windows, la respuesta que tienes te ayudará, para Linux es otro cantar, pero podrías investigar por el lado de https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así?

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_long, c_wchar_p, c_ulong, c_void_p,Structure

class COORD(Structure):
        """struct in wincon.h"""
        _fields_ = [
            ('X', SHORT),
            ('Y', SHORT),
        ]

gHandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle (c_long (-11))


def move (y, x):
   value = COORD(x,y)
   ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition (gHandle, c_ulong (value))


def addstr (string):
   ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteConsoleW (gHandle, c_wchar_p (string), c_ulong(len (string)), c_void_p (), None)
```

La función move se le pasan los parámetros x,y que son las coordenadas y en la función addstr recibe un parámetro que es lo que queremos que escriba

Comment: Explica tu código por favor, no es solo poner el código sino una explicación

Comment: La función mover se le pasan los parámetros x,y que son las coordenadas y en la función addstr recibe un parámetro que es lo que queremos que escriba

Comment: Edita tu respuesta y agrega tu explicación ahí